# Find pattern with Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a log file with multiple lines of text from multiple log files.  I am attempting to send the log files contents in the body of an email using Send-MailMessage.

My question is : I am trying to extract lines a string of text `Exception` from multiple log files. I want to match this within  if statement.  I have tried script like below but no luck. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Log file content :

```
25/Dec/2018 11:50:05.224 ERROR  3805     com.crm.dao.CrmDaoJdbcImpl(L:608) - Exception created
Rerun the transaction.
               at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
               at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1522)
               at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
               at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
               at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
```

After extract desired output:

```
25/Dec/2018 11:50:05.224 ERROR  3805     com.crm.dao.CrmDaoJdbcImpl(L:608) - Exception created
```

Here is a snippet of the script for reference.

```
$SourceDir = "C:\Temp\TEMP2"
#$GCI_Fiter = '*.txt'
$Include=@("*.log","*.txt")

$FileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceDir -Include "$Include" -File

foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList)   {
$FLI_Content = Get-Content -LiteralPath $FL_Item.FullName -Raw

if ( ???????? )  {
$ExceptionLines = $FLI_Content | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'Exception' | ForEach-Object {$_.ToString().Trim()}

$ExceptionLines
}

else {
Write-Warning "Could not find Exception keyword from '$FL_Item.FullName'.."
}


}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You could filter for lines that begin with at or rerun `(^\s*at|^\s*Rerun).*$` (not pro at regex myself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find all lines that contain the word "Exception":

```
Get-Content -Path $file.FullName | Select-String "Exception"
```

If you want to test to see if there are any lines containing the word "Exception" then it's as easy as assigning the results of the above command to a variable and testing for a value!

```
$results = Get-Content -Path $file.FullName | Select-String "Exception"

if ($results) {
    Write-Output "Exception found"
}
else {
    Write-Output "No exception found"
}
```

Comment: Thanks , My question is :  I want to match this  within if statement.  So How do I return a True value from PowerShell if a string (Exception) match conditions? My command : $FLI_Content | Select-String 'Exception' | ForEach-Object {$_.ToString().Trim()}  I want to use this within if statement